# There are an infinite number of primes $p$ of the form $p=2^2+a^2$, where $a$ is also a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A claim from David Burton's *[Elementary Number Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073383147)*:

> There are an infinite number of primes $p$ of the form $p=2^2+a^2$,
>   where $a$ is also a prime.

Comment: In what page is that?

Comment: I suppose it is a typo, because it is also weird that $2^2$ isn't written as 4.

Comment: @Alamos it's on page number 270, question 2 (b)

Comment: @wythagoras It's intentionally done so. The chapter this conjecture falls under is "Representing integers as the sum of squares".

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt it is possible to prove the claim with simple arguments, since the weaker claim:

> "There exist an infinite number of prime $p$ such that $p$ is a square
>   plus one"

is still a conjecture, namely the [Landau's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_problems). As far as we know, there exist an infinite number of primes of the form $a^2+b^4$ (Iwaniec, Friedlander) and of the form $a^3+2b^3$ (Heath-Brown).

Comment: And $a,b$ are still primes?

Comment: @AlexM.: no, just integers. To require that $a,b$ are primes, too, just makes the problem even more difficult.